# Split multiple strings into a list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, ienumerable

I have the following code:

```
public class Info
{
  public string Name;
  public string Num;
}

string s1 = "a,b";
string s2 = "1,2";

IEnumerable<Info> InfoSrc =
    from name in s1.Split(',')
    from num in s2.Split(',')
    select new Info()
    {
        Name = name,
        Num = num
    };

List<Info> listSrc = InfoSrc.ToList();
```

I would like my `listSrc` result to contain two `Info` items whose `Name` and `Num` properties are:

```
a, 1
b, 2
```

However, the code I show above results in four items:

```
a, 1
a, 2
b, 1
b, 2
```

Comment: will the splits always be the same length?

Comment: Look into `Enumerable.Zip`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Zip`:

```
IEnumerable<Info> InfoSrc = s1.Split(',')
    .Zip(s2.Split(','), (name, num) => new Info(){ Name = name, Num = num });
```

If you need to map more than two collections to properties you could  chain multiple `Zip` together with an anonymous type holding the second and third:

```
IEnumerable<Info> InfoSrc = s1.Split(',')
    .Zip(s2.Split(',').Zip(s3.Split(','), (second, third) => new { second, third }),
        (first, x) => new Info { Name = first, Num = x.second, Prop3 = x.third });
```

Here is a hopefully more readable version:

```
var arrays = new List<string[]> { s1.Split(','), s2.Split(','), s3.Split(',') };
int minLength = arrays.Min(arr => arr.Length);  // to be safe, same behaviour as Zip
IEnumerable<Info> InfoSrc = Enumerable.Range(0, minLength)
 .Select(i => new Info
 {
     Name = arrays[0][i],
     Num = arrays[1][i],
     Prop3 = arrays[2][i]
 });
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what's going on, basically you split `s1` into an array of strings, then `Zip` that array with another array created from `s2`. This creates a collection of elements in accordance to whatever the third argument is-- which in this case is the constructor for the `Info` object. So basically you just get a collection of `Info` items?

Comment: @sab669: yes, but not a collection. Currently it's just a query. If you want a collection you need to append `ToList` or `ToArray`. `Enumerable.Zip`  enumerates two sequences simultaneously and returns the items which are at the same index.

Comment: What happens when I need three split strings of equal size?  Info now has 3 fields.
string s1 = "a,b";
string s2 = "1,2";
string s3 = "G,J";

Comment: I more so meant collection is just the "generic" English term that you have a bunch of objects. But technically speaking, I guess I'm not 100% certain on the differences between the `Collection` / `ICollection` class + interface versus `IEnumerable`. Not sure when to use one or the other.

Comment: @user3716892 You should just be able to zip `InfoSrc` and `s3` together again and then assign that third property? I'm sure Tim has a better solution though. `Zip` says that the first and second arguments don't have to be of the same type so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @user3716892: one approach is chaining them as shown in my answer. But i must admit that this isn't very readable anymore. Another approach is putting the `string[]` into a `List<string[]>` or `string[][]` and then you can access them via index. I could show you that approach if you want.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the number of items in each list is equal, it looks like you're trying to [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) them together...

```
s1.Split(',').Zip(s2.Split(','), (name, num) => new Info{Name = name, Num = num})
```

Comment: Should be: `IEnumerable<Info> InfoSrc = s1.Split(',').Zip(s2.Split(','), (a, b) => new Info { Name = a, Num = b });`